# is it possible to set custom headers on js <script> requests?

Tags: javascript, http-headers

Is something like this possible?

```
<script src="http://myserver.com/some.js" my-custom-header="foo"></script>
```

Update (a bit more detail):

I've been asked if there was a way to communicate some parameters to the server as part of the script request using headers instead of GET params. I said, "no," but thought I'd double check.

Comment: Which header(s) did you want to have set?

Comment: Why can't you use GET params?

Comment: The worry is about running out of room in the url space. And also having to parse them out, I guess. (I gather we have a custom parser, so it's not as simple as $_GET['myParam'].)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: no. By default a script tag will just retrieve the resource specified in the `src` attribute.

However, if you use an AJAX request to retrieve the script (and add it later/execute it), you can use the `setRequestHeader` function of the `XMLHttpRequest` object (see http://www.developertutorials.com/learn-ajax/custom-http-headers-2643.php).

You could also use more complex methods, such as using `mod_rewrite` to rewrite paths, and include the parameters in the url. The best solution depends on what you want to do, and how much control you have over the server.

Comment: I'm currently using one script to document.write another. I had thought of ajax, but instead of the script tag (i.e. to get the results of the second script), not as a means to get the script itself. I'll explore that.

Comment: This isn't completely accurate, at least the part about setting headers on GET requests... that *is* possible with GET requests, and it is oftentimes used for authentication on HTTPS requests, since the headers would be encrypted. However, you *are* correct that it's not possible to set headers on script tag requests, but that has nothing to do with it being a GET request. See [xhr.setRequestHeader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader()) for details. Hope this helps.

Comment: On reading this again, I see in your second paragraph you did address the issue of setting headers on AJAX requests, but your first statement could make people think this doesn't work with GET requests at all. Maybe you could just edit out the first sentence, as that would help make it more clear. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

No. You'll need to set the headers on the server that's serving up the JS file.

EDIT: I misinterpreted what you meant, it turns out you wanted to set a request header, not a response header. This is still not possible (from HTML) as far as I know.