# How do I control request headers set by requirejs?

Tags: requirejs

Specifically I want to add a client-set request ID to troubleshoot some network problems. I see that requireJS allows for control over query string parameters, e.g. for cache busting, but putting a unique request ID in the URL will cache bust (when I don't want to) and make debugging hard (breakpoints will be set on e.g. `/resource?request_id=288832uc8vasd8`).

Comment: Please note that "You cannot do that" is a valid, potentially correct question. No need to close this question if that is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequireJS is going to  pull scripts in by adding them as `<script/>` tags and then waiting for the callback to fire.  As far as I know, you can't add headers to the request the the `<script/>` tag fires so I don't think you can add headers for RequireJS calls.

From there, you can consider the answer to [is it possible to set custom headers on js  requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4866851/691711):

> Short answer: no. By default a script tag will just retrieve the
>   resource specified in the src attribute.